# How can I ignore all cmake dev warnings from subdirectories?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-language

I am using a few external libraries that are included as git submodules using the `add_subdirectory` command. Some of them are using old versions of cmake and they're issuing warnings about policies CMP0048 and CMP0077.

Is there a way to turn off all cmake warnings for these libraries?

I've tried explicitly setting the policies to `OLD` before including the projects but it didn't help.

I'd prefer not to edit any files in the git submodule because then there would be extra steps when someone has to clone my project's repo and build it on their machine.

Answer (score 1):

> I know this is a old questions, but in case someone stumbles upon the same problem, here are my findings.

### Why didn't your attempts work?

Setting the policies before the `add_subdirectory()` call won't work, because [cmake_minimum_required()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) implicitly set a specific set of policies, depending on the required version, which might override the set policies. Also, setting them explicitly to `OLD` has no effect even if they weren't overridden, since there is no distinction between being `OLD` because it is the default for that version or because it was explicitly set. A warning is issued in both cases, because as the documentation of every policy states, the old behavior is deprecated by definition.

### Possible Solutions

I can think of the following solutions:

1. Use the *undocumented* variable `CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS`, which is also set when passing `-Wno-dev` on the command line (see [cmake.cxx](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/v3.25.1/Source/cmake.cxx#L3924)). Since you probably don't want this to have an influence on your project and disable all developer warning there as well, you should restore the original value after the `add_subdirectory()` call:

   ```cpp
   set(no_dev_warnings_backup "$CACHE{CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS}")
   set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS ON CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   add_subdirectory(...)
   set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS ${no_dev_warnings_backup} CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
   ```

   The variable might be undocumented and therefore not that reliable as documented variables, but I wouldn't worry too much about it. It has been around since the CMake 2.x days and is unlikely to go anywhere.
2. Set [CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP<NNNN>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) to `NEW`:

   ```cpp
   set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0048 "NEW")
   set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 "NEW")
   add_subdirectory(...)
   ```

   Note that this doesn't just disable the warnings, but alters how CMake processes the affected `CMakeLists.txt` files. **This might break the build of your external libraries!**
3. Use [CMAKE_PROJECT__INCLUDE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_PROJECT-NAME_INCLUDE.html) or one of its related variables to inject some CMake code into the build of the external libraries. The injected code could then call `cmake_policy(SET CMP<NNNN> NEW)` to override the policy. Note that just like the 2. solution, **this could break the build!**
4. Instead of a git submodule, you could use [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) which fetches the external libraries and calls `add_subdirectory()` one them. Since `FetchContent` is quite related to [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) it allows to patch the retrieved sources, so you can fix/customize the build of the external libraries:

   ```cpp
   include(FetchContent)
   find_package(Patch REQUIRED)
   FetchContent_Declare(myextlib
      GIT_REPOSITORY <url>
      GIT_TAG <tag_or_hash>
      PATCH_COMMAND "${Patch_EXECUTABLE}" -p1 < path/to/myextlib.patch
   )
   FetchContent_MakeAvailable(myextlib)
   ```

   More on diffs and patches can be found [here](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/diffs-patches). Alternatively, you also use [git apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) as patch command, since you use Git anyway.

### Recommendations

I would recommend either 1 or 4. Approach 4 is the most flexible, since you could improve the build in other aspects as well, if necessary, but it is also the most involved one, since whenever you bump the version of your external libraries you also need to take care of your patches and check whether they still work etc. In case you don't need that flexibility and only care about disabling warnings, approach 1 would be the most straight forward solution.